# Bar chart is giving negative values

Tags: ios, charts, swift3, xscale

I am using Charts API and implementing chart. I am new in that and there is no proper documentation for Swift 3.

I tried and implemented but don't know how to remove that negative scale for y. How can I start my graph from 0 only, so it does not show a negative y scale?

Below is my code:

```
fileprivate func ChartViewProperty() {

    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
    barChartView.fitBars = true
    barChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)

    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months)
    barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    value.append([jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jly,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec])
    setChart(dataPoints: months, values: value)
}.
```

Image:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting axisMinValue Property

I guess barChartView.xAxis.axisMinValue

Comment: I tried that but not helped.
I did  barChartView.xAxis.axisMinValue = 0.5

Comment: do u got any solution for this ?

Comment: try this         barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
fileprivate func ChartViewProperty() {

    //barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

    //barChartView
    barChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true

    //Space between x axis
    barChartView.xAxis.spaceMin  = 1.0
    barChartView.xAxis.spaceMax  = 1.0

    //Left axis bottom
    barChartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0

    //Label Position
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    //Description
    barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""

    //Fit Bar
    barChartView.fitBars = false

    //Pinch Zoom
    barChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false

    //Right x axis enabled
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

    //Animate barchart
    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or an addendum to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This line removes all negative values from the bar chart:

```
chartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0
```